# Rails Routing error on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to implement a simple private message system using rails, and it works fine however when building the reply system, i get errors. here is the code:

```
def show
  @message = current_user.messages.find(params[:id])
    if @message != nil
      @sender = User.find(@message.id).email
      @replies = @message.replies
      @reply = Reply.new
      @reply.message_id = params[:id]
      @reply.user_id = current_user.id
   else
      index_redirect
   end
```

end

```
  def reply
    @reply = Reply.new(params[:reply])
    if @reply.save
      set_flash "Reply sent"
      show_redirect
    else
      set_flash "Error, please try again"
      show_redirect
    end
  end
```

and the view:

```
<h1>Messages#show</h1>
```

```
<h2>replies</h2>
<div>
    <%- @replies.each do |reply| %>
        <%= content_tag :span, reply.content %>
        <%= content_tag :span, reply.created_at %>
        <%= content_tag :span, User.find(reply.user_id).email %>
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for @reply, :as => :reply, :url => { :action => :reply } do |reply| %>
        <%= reply.text_area :content %>
        <%= reply.submit "Reply" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

finally the routes:

```
  resources :messages do
    collection do
      delete 'destroy'
      post   'reply'
    end
  end



 messages DELETE /messages(.:format)            messages#destroy
      reply_messages POST   /messages/reply(.:format)      messages#reply
                     GET    /messages(.:format)            messages#index
                     POST   /messages(.:format)            messages#create
         new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)        messages#new
        edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)   messages#edit
             message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#show
                     PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#update
                     DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#destroy
```

**however on form submit i get this error:**

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess,  As you have your form, it is sending a `POST` to an action that only receives `GETs` and that is why you get your error.
You either needs to send to the right action, `create` (as it accepts `POST`) in this case or set the `:method` to `:get`.

In your view, the following is the example to change the form into `get` method.

```
<%= form_for @reply, :as => :reply, :url => { :action => :reply }, :html => {:method => :post} do |reply| %>
  <%= reply.text_area :content %>
  <%= reply.submit "Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: actually the action only recieves `POSTS` it does't allow `GETS`, ` `resources :messages do
    collection do
      delete 'destroy'
      post   'reply'
    end
  end`

Comment: Try with just `<% form_for @reply do |reply | %>`